# Java Nesting Ignore Inner Attributes

Tags: java, json, oop, serialization

I have an object model that is handling relations between types.  These references sometimes loop back around on themselves, and to stop that (in say a REST call) I am using things like the `@JsonIgnore` tag to make sure I don't get infinite nest recursion.

The issue with this is more a question of context.  If I want an item to be included in one spot but not another (if being nested), `@JsonIgnore` stops it from both spots.

Example:

```
public class A implements Serializable{
    Set<B> bs;
    Set<C> cs;
    ...
}

public class B implements Serializable{
    String name;
    Set<D> ds;
    ...
}

public class C implements Serializable{
    B b;
    ...
}

public class D implements Serializable{
    ...
}
```

If `A` is my main container which is transporting the objects.  In the context of `B` as listed in `A`, I want the `Set<D>` to show.  When an object `B` is used in context of `C` however, I want to hide `Set<D>` and only show the name.

If I were to mark `@JsonIgnore` on `B.ds` it wouldn't show up in either case.  Is there some annotation/customization I can put on `C.b` to ignore inner attributes?  `@JsonIgnore("ds")` or something?  Is there another way to handle this entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can annotate the fields with `@JsonView` and then specify the serialization view you want to use in particular circumstances. [Here's a post about using it with SpringMVC](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring) but the approach would be the same regardless.

So in your specific example,

```
public class View {
    interface Full {}
    interface Summary {}
}

public class B implements Serializable{
    @JsonView({View.Summary,View.Full})
    String name;

    @JsonView(View.Full)
    Set<D> ds;

}
```

Comment: Would this solve it though?  When I print/call my generation of `A`, I would define the View I am using.  That would be in effect on `A.bs` and `C.b` (through `A.cs`)?

This assumes I am using 2 different calls, one to generate a "full" and one hiding things for the "summary".  In my problem it is one in the same call.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get that in your original question. If it's the same call and you need to dynamically determine whether or not to include different instances of the same class from the same method, this won't do what you want. To do that, you'd probably have to bite the bullet and write a custom Serializer and install it on your objectMapper.

Comment: that makes sense (and I was kinda afraid of it), but I think I was finding similar "write a custom" feelings elsewhere I was looking.  This answer looks like it would still be really useful to people and similar, gonna approve anyway :) thanks!